# Update Postgres Table Statistics based on Entire Table (All Rows)

Tags: database, postgresql, statistics

What is the process/commands of updating the statistics of a LARGE postgres db table, based on ALL the records and not just a sample of the records? (which is the default behaviour of ANALYZE command)

I run ANALYZE on a large table (>10mil records) and it only used a fraction of the records to update the statistics.

Comment: There is no possibilities to do an UPDATE of planer statistis for all the rows. Because the process will run too much longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such process or command. The highest allowed setting of default_statistics_target (or the per-column variant) is 10_000, and that would lead to a sample size of only 3_000_000.  You would need to modify the code and recompile if you want to do something different than that.

Comment: Just wondering - since it is a random sample - how possible can it be that the ANALYZE statistics is not going to be acurate? Is there a way somehow to ensure that it is accurate (or make it _more_ accurate)??

Comment: Do you have a specific problem in mind?  The n_distinct estimate, for example, is known to have problems with certain kinds of data because the sampling algorithm is not strictly independent from row to row.  Too few pages have exactly one row sampled from them, and too many have either 0 rows or >=2 rows.  But you can manually override the n_distinct value on a per-column basis, which is generally going to work better than increasing the sample size will.

Comment: @ jjanes indeed not - nothing specific. Just wondering if we can rely on ANALYZE to update the stats for the exec planner - or we need to use more 'brutal' methods (recalc indexes - vacuum e.t.c., I hope these are correct though, I don't want to mislead anyone reading this...)